# Android List View easier way

Tags: android, listview

Is there any easier way to do this?

```
String[] values = new String[] { "1337", "2", "3DPD", "4", "10q",
        "10x", "A C?", "AAF", "ADAD", "ADIH", "ADIP", "AEAP", "AFAICR",
        "AFAICS"

};

final String[] title = new String[] { "1337", "2", "3DPD", "4", "10q",
        "10x", "A C?", "AAF", "ADAD", "ADIH", "ADIP", "AEAP", "AFAICR",
        "AFAICS"

};

final String[] content = new String[] {
        " From the word Leet, derived from the word elite",
        "too, or to",
        " 3-Dimensional Pig Disgusting, denotes two dimensions are superior to reality",
        "For", "Thank you", "Thanks", "AH! SI?", "As A Friend",
        "Another Day Another Dollar", "Another Day In Hell",
        " Another Day in Paradise", "As Early As Possible",
        "As far as I can recall / remember", " As far as I can see",};
```

When user clicks list item I need to pass information from every array to another activity , example: User clicks item with name "1337" and now I'm taking paramteres from three arrays with position 0 ... And I have to do this for every click :

```
switch (itemPosition) {
    case 0:
        Intent intent = new Intent(DisplayMessageActivity.this, AboutSlangs.class);
        intent.putExtra(TITLE, title[0]);
        intent.putExtra(CONTENT, content[0]);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
```

Any easier way?

Comment: Have a hashmap, title as key and value as content

Comment: I'm asking about switch statement not about arrays :D

Comment: You're another activity is the same every time or it changes depend upon the position?

Comment: It depends on which item user clicks

Comment: I figure it out ... Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all create a model like

```
class DataModel implements Serialiable{

private String title ;
private String value ;
private String description ;

DataModel(String ... data){

this.title = data[0] ;
this.value = data[1];
this.description = data[2] ;

}


// Generate getter setter for all 

}
```

Now generate the arrayList like

```
ArrayList <DataModel> arr = new ArrayList<DataModel>();

for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++){

DataModel model = new DataModel("title","value","description"); //change logic according to requirement

arr.add(model); 

}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    DataModel model = arr.get(position);

    Intent intent = new Intent(DisplayMessageActivity.this, Target.class);
    intent.putExtra("DATA", model);

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: But he's asking how to simplify the switch statement, not how to simplify his arrays. He wants the target activity to be different for each item click.

Comment: switch case will faster then accessing the class from array thats why i didn't included in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could add another array like this:

```
Class<?>[] target =  { ActivityA.class, ActivityB.class, ActivityC.class };
```

and position them appropriately to your tile/content arrays. This way you wouldn't need a switch statement at all, on onItemClick simply get the position and do:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(DisplayMessageActivity.this, target[position]);
    intent.putExtra("TITLE", title[position]);
    intent.putExtra("CONTENT", content[position]);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```